# Looking for string with only one number and extract that number

Tags: r, regex, dataframe

I have a data frame with different sorts of commission in it. As there is no specific pattern for the commission, it is so difficult to extract the numbers; however, as the starting point I want to do the followings:

1. Finding commissions that include **only** one number in it
2. Decide if the number is in the form of **$abcde (example: $1000 or $12350)** or **a.b% (example: 2.1%)**
3. If the number is in **$abcde** extract the number and add it to **Fixed** column, if **a.b%** extract the number and save it in **Second** column

The data frame is shown below:

```
structure(list(commission = c("SELLING COMMISSION IS $9000", 
"NO COMMISSION", "SELLING BROKER COMMISSION:$26729", "AND 3.1% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE AND GST", 
"3.5% - 1ST $100000", "3.3% AND 1.2% PLUS GST", "3.2% - 1.0%", 
"1.2% FULL PRICE", "1% SELLING PRICE"), First = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), `cut-off` = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Second = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Bonus = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Fixed = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-9L))
```

So the expected result is like the one shown below:

```
                                     commission First cut-off Second Bonus Fixed
1                   SELLING COMMISSION IS $9000  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  9000
2                                 NO COMMISSION  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3              SELLING BROKER COMMISSION:$26729  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  26729
4 AND 3.1% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE AND GST  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5                            3.5% - 1ST $100000  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6                        3.3% AND 1.2% PLUS GST  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7                                   3.2% - 1.0%  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8                               1.2% FULL PRICE  <NA>    <NA>   1.2   <NA>  <NA>
9                              1% SELLING PRICE  <NA>    <NA>   1     <NA>  <NA>
```

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df %>% 
  mutate(
    cond = lengths(str_extract_all(commission, "\\$?\\d*\\.?\\d+%?")) < 2L, 
    Fixed = if_else(cond, str_extract(commission, "(?<=\\$)\\d*\\.?\\d+"), NA_character_), 
    Second = if_else(cond, str_extract(commission, "\\d*\\.?\\d+(?=%)"), NA_character_), 
    cond = NULL
  )
```

Output

```
                                     commission First cut-off Second Bonus Fixed
1                   SELLING COMMISSION IS $9000  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  9000
2                                 NO COMMISSION  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
3              SELLING BROKER COMMISSION:$26729  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA> 26729
4 AND 3.1% 1ST $100000 AND 1.2% BALANCE AND GST  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
5                            3.5% - 1ST $100000  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
6                        3.3% AND 1.2% PLUS GST  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
7                                   3.2% - 1.0%  <NA>    <NA>   <NA>  <NA>  <NA>
8                               1.2% FULL PRICE  <NA>    <NA>    1.2  <NA>  <NA>
9                              1% SELLING PRICE  <NA>    <NA>      1  <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks, can you please explain how the code works? especially the `cond` part. What does `2L` do there? I am guessing you are creating a condition and then decide based on the condition; however, it's not clear for me how it's working

Comment: `2L` is basically 2 of an integer type. That line just extracts all numbers and test whether each match group has less than 2 elements. Try this `str_extract_all(df$commission, "\\$?\\d*\\.?\\d+%?")` and this `lengths(str_extract_all(commission, "\\$?\\d*\\.?\\d+%?")) < 2L` in R console. @Roozbeh_you